# Remark about $\sup(f+g)$ and $\sup (A+B)$

Tags: real-analysis

**1.** Let $A$ and $B$ are some nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Define $A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$ it's easy to prove that $$\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B \qquad(1)$$

**2.** Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are some real-valued functions on $[a,b]$. Then $$\sup\limits_{[a,b]} (f(x)+g(x))\leqslant\sup\limits_{[a,b]} f(x)+\sup\limits_{[a,b]} g(x) \qquad(2)$$
**Remark:** By the way strict inequality hold for function $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1-x$ on $[0,1]$.

I am confused that in $(1)$ we have equality and in $(2)$ inequality but $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are also some nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and by $(1)$ we must have equality in $(2)$. What's the problem?

Can anyone explain this phenomenon in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one you are taking the sum over fixed $x\in[a,b]$, whereas in the case of $A+B$ you are summing over all combinations of $a$ and $b$. You would achieve an equality in the second case if you instead had

$$\sup_{x,y\in[a,b]}(f(x)+g(y))$$

Comment: What means "you are taking the sum over fixed $x\in [a,b]$"? Sorry if my question sounds stupid since sometimes I have problems with English.

Comment: Bad phrasing, sorry. The sup is only considering the set $\{f(x)+g(x)\mid x\in [a,b]\}$, instead of $\{f(x)+g(y)\mid x,y\in[a,b]\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You wil have the same equality as (1) by considerating $f([a,b])$ and $g([a,b])$ but here it's not the case : when you take the supremum of the sum you have to take the same $x$ to evaluate $f$ and $g$.